# Is it possible to iterate through a table variable using a cursor?

Tags: sql-server-2005, cursor, table-variable

In SQL Server 2005, is it possible to iterate through a table variable using a cursor?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is the reason for the question?

Comment: It's because when I try to use a cursor over a table variable, it gives me the next error: "The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns". I do this inside an stored procedure, and when I change the table variable for a temporal table, it works fine. Don't know why this happens, because I made a small test outside the procedure, and I can iterate over the table variable whitout issues.